# Neilas HaChag on a Yom Tov that ends on Friday

Tags: passover, sukkot, shavuos, simchat-torah

This year Simchas Torah comes out on Friday. It can also happen that Pesach or Shavuos finishes on Friday in Eretz Yisroel. Is there a Neilas HaChag if Yom Tov ends on Friday?

Comment: Way too much food to do that

Comment: Is Neilas HaChag a codified minhag such that there are rules about it, or just something people like to do?

Comment: What is Neilas HaChag?  (I mean ok, literally it sounds like it's about the festival going out, but it seems to involve food?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Shabbos follows a Yom Tov, the *kedusha* (holiness) of the Yom Tov "extends" itself into the Shabbos. (Some don't sing Shabbos *Zemiros* because of this.)
So, many make Neilas HaChag by Shalosh Seudos.

One **should not** eat a large meal on Friday close to Shabbos.

Comment: d a, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for that nice idea. I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: That is what I thought, however I saw a Shul that made it on Semini Atzeres going into Simchas Torah and was wondering if anyone else did that.

Comment: Isaac, thanks for the welcome! I got "introduced" to this great site from YWCR. I am getting to know it and getting to enjoy it!!! (I am "d a" from the CR!)

I was not really responding to what Eretz Yisroel does, however, one should not eat a lot before any Yom Tov, Erev Yom Tov, going from one day to another, from Yom Tov to Shabbos or from Shabbos to Yom Tov. So that you will enjoy the Yom Tov/Shabbos meal better.

However, some eat in the Sukkah on Shmini Atzeres. So some make a small (or large!) party before leaving the Sukkah. One shouldn't eat too much, to leave room 4 the meal at night

Comment: d a, I'm glad you're enjoying m.y. That link on YWCR brought a lot of interested people here, but only a few stuck around and made contributions, like you, becoming interesting as well as interested.
http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/good-websites , in case anyone's wondering