# What is the source for Neilas Hachag?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag

*Neilas Hachag* (as I understand it since there doesn't appear to be any real rules about it) is a tradition to eat some level of special meal as *yom tov* ends, typically associated with Sukkos, Pesach, and Shavuot but not necessarily restricted to those.

I've found material about the spiritual significance and symbolism behind it but nothing about the source for this tradition.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Daniel and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Note that the clearer you can be in describing your question, the better answer you will get. In the case above, don't hesitate to describe your research to date and description of what you are asking above. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3108/neilas-hachag-on-a-yom-tov-that-ends-on-friday

Comment: @rosends thanks for the related link. Seen it before but doesn't help - the question asking if it is a codified minhag was unfortunately unanswered :(

Comment: It appears that something similar is also celebrated at the Ponevezh Yeshiva in Israel. See this link: http://www.bhol.co.il/news/771713

Comment: This would seem to relate to the Moshiach's Seudah made on Acharon shel Pesach after minchah that was instituted by the Baal Shem Tov and popularized for the public by the 5th Lubavitcher Rebbe, Rabbi Shalom Dov Ber, z"l.

Comment: According to this link from Wikipedia, the Vilna Gaon z"l also followed this practice.  https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/סעודת_משיח

Comment: @Yaacov No, the Vilna Gaon followed a different practice that only ate an extra meal at the end of Pesach and not for this reason.

Comment: Other than what was mentioned re the *Moshiach meal* with the Chaba"d reasoning, the *Ne'ilat Hachag* on the other holidays seems to be a more recent invention, mainly begun from about a decade ago. I've been in various neighborhoods and mainly Ashkenazy shuls  from MO to Hareidi. Not one did this extra meal. Two places have told me that their main motive was to encourage people to form a minyan for Mincha (food is an incentive.) A few others have said that this is a "fund raiser" for the shul. They request sponsorships or contributions and the shul makes some profit above the cost of the food

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it stems from [Shir Hashirim Rabbah 7:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shir_HaShirim_Rabbah.7.2.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> דָּבָר אַחֵר, מַה יָּפוּ פְעָמַיִךְ בַּנְּעָלִים, בִּשְׁנֵי נְעָלִים, אָמַר רַבִּי חָמָא בְּרַבִּי חֲנִינָא לִשְׁנֵי פְּרַגְמָטִיטִין שֶׁנִּכְנְסוּ לִמְדִינָה, עָנָה אֶחָד מֵהֶם וְאָמַר לַחֲבֵרוֹ אִם פּוֹתְחִין אָנוּ שְׁנֵינוּ כְּאֶחָד בַּמְּדִינָה, אָנוּ עוֹשִׂין אַפְרַגְיֵיס בַּמְּדִינָה, אֶלָּא פְּתַח אַתָּה שַׁבַּתְּךָ וַאֲנִי שַׁבַּתִּי. רַבִּי חֲנַנְיָא בְּרֵיהּ דְּרַבִּי אַיְּבִי אָמַר מַה יָּפוּ פְעָמַיִךְ בַּנַּעַל, אֵין כְּתִיב כָּאן, אֶלָּא בַּנְּעָלִים, שְׁתֵּי נְעָלִים, נְעִילָה בְּפֶסַח וּנְעִילָה בֶּחָג, אָמַר לָהֶם הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לְיִשְׂרָאֵל, אַתֶּם נוֹעֲלִים לְפָנַי בַּחַג וַאֲנִי נוֹעֵל לִפְנֵיכֶם בַּפֶּסַח. אַתֶּם נוֹעֲלִים לְפָנַי בַּחַג, וַאֲנִי פּוֹתֵחַ וּמַשִּׁיב רוּחוֹת וּמַעֲלֶה עֲנָנִים וּמוֹרִיד גְּשָׁמִים וּמַזְרִיחַ חַמָּה וּמְגַדֵּל צְמָחִים וּמְדַשֵּׁן פֵּרוֹת וְעוֹרֵךְ שֻׁלְחָן לִפְנֵי כָל אֶחָד וְאֶחָד צְרָכָיו, וּלְכָל גְּוִיָּה וּגְוִיָּה כְּדֵי מַחְסוֹרָהּ, וַאֲנִי נוֹעֵל לִפְנֵיכֶם בְּפֶסַח, וְאַתֶּם יוֹצְאִים וְקוֹצְרִים וְדָשִׁין וְזוֹרִים וְעוֹשִׂים כָּל צָרְכֵיכֶם בַּשָֹּׂדֶה וּמוֹצְאִין אוֹתָהּ מְלֵאָה בְּרָכוֹת. אָמַר רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן לֵוִי רְאוּיָה הָיְתָה הָעֲצֶרֶת שֶׁל חַג שֶׁתְּהֵא רְחוֹקָה חֲמִשִּׁים יוֹם כְּנֶגֶד הָעֲצֶרֶת שֶׁל פֶּסַח, אֶלָּא עֲצֶרֶת שֶׁל חַג עַל יְדֵי שֶׁהֵן יוֹצְאִים מִן הַקַּיִץ לַחֹרֶף לֵית בְּיוֹמַיְהוּ דְּיֵיזְלוּן וְיֵיתוּן, מָשָׁל לְמָה הַדָּבָר דּוֹמֶה לְמֶלֶךְ שֶׁהָיוּ לוֹ בָּנוֹת הַרְבֵּה, מֵהֶן נְשׂוּאוֹת בְּמָקוֹם קָרוֹב, וּמֵהֶן נְשׂוּאוֹת לְמָקוֹם רָחוֹק, יוֹם אֶחָד בָּאוּ כֻּלָּם לִשְׁאֹל שְׁלוֹם הַמֶּלֶךְ אֲבִיהֶם, אָמַר הַמֶּלֶךְ אֵלּוּ שֶׁנְּשׂוּאוֹת בְּמָקוֹם קָרוֹב אִית בְּעוֹנָתָהּ לְמֵיזַל וּלְמֵיתֵי, וְאִלֵּין שֶׁנְּשׂוּאוֹת בְּמָקוֹם רָחוֹק לֵית בְּעוֹנָתָהּ לֵיזֵיל וּלְמֵיתֵי, אֶלָּא עַד דְּאִינוּן כֻּלְּהוֹן אֶצְלִי הָכָא נַעֲבֵד כֻּלָּן חַד יוֹם טַב וְנֶחְדֵּי עִמָּן. כָּךְ עֲצֶרֶת שֶׁל פֶּסַח עַד דְּאִינוּן נָפְקִין מֵהַחֹרֶף לַקַּיִץ אָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא אִית בְּיוֹמָא לְמֵיזַל וּלְמֵיתֵי, אֲבָל עֲצֶרֶת שֶׁל חַג עַל יְדֵי שֶׁהֵן יוֹצְאִין מֵהַקַּיִץ לַחֹרֶף, וַאֲבַק דְּרָכִים קָשֶׁה, וְיָדוֹת דְּרָכִים קָשׁוֹת, לְפִיכָךְ אֵינָהּ רְחוֹקָה חֲמִשִּׁים יוֹם, אָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לֵית בְּיוֹמַיָא לְמֵיזַל וּלְמֵיתֵי, אֶלָּא עַד דְּאִינוּן הָכָא נַעֲבֵד כֻּלָּן חַד יוֹם טַב וְנֶחְדֵּי, לְכָךְ משֶׁה מַזְהִיר לְיִשְׂרָאֵל וְאוֹמֵר לָהֶם (במדבר כט, לה): בַּיּוֹם הַשְּׁמִינִי עֲצֶרֶת תִּהְיֶה לָכֶם, הֱוֵי אוֹמֵר: מַה יָּפוּ פְעָמַיִךְ בַּנְּעָלִים.

Comment: This is the beginning of an answer, but I'll need to see a bit more before upvoting.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What does this have to do with the tradition of having a meal at the end of Yom Tov? He wasn't looking for the first time the words appear.